# Bitlocker on Hyper-V server

Tags: security, hyper-v, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I have installed Hyper-V server on my new machine and then I added the Bitlocker function and initialized TPM. Now, I am trying to enable Bitlocker on the HDD.

I need:

- encryption key saved on TPM
- *recovery* key saved on USB flash

  - *key will be printed and put into safe*
  - *the flash will then be formatted*
- encryption algorithm AES256-XTS

I tried to use the following command:

```
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod XtsAes256 -RecoveryKeyProtector -RecoveryKeyPath "D:"
```

(I used this [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps))

The problem is that the file created on flash is not readable, therefore I can't print it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Hyper-V Server?

Comment: Is it in a domain?  Why not just let it backup to AD.

Comment: The recovery key saved to USB is not intended to be printed. It's intended to remain on digital media to be plugged into the computer if it is necessary to use the key.

Comment: @Davidw - It's Hyper-V server 2016

Comment: @Zoredache - No, it isn't.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Is there any other way to get it on a paper?